How to add sidecar ip from netbox
I have multiple Prometheus with thanos sidecar running on different clusters. And the endpoint of the sidecar is available in the netbox. The cluster sending data can be on and off, so I want to configure the endpoints in the thanos querier as a new endpoint in added in the netbox.
Is there a method that does this dynamically?
